# I need help with this Standard Uniform random variable problem

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, computational-mathematics

[Click here for problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkZFf.png)

I need help on how to do b,c and d. Can I please have an idea of how to start it because i have no idea how to do this.